# UIImage imageWithData memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiimage

Using ASIHTTP, the code below is in the ImageDownloader class. I get a memory leak, which is added at the bottom, but I don't know why. I thought tempImage would be autoreleased without me doing anything?

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];

    if (tempImage.size.width > 250.0f && tempImage.size.height > 180.0f)
    {
        self.image = tempImage;
        self.circleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hover.png"];

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addImageToModel:)])
            [self.delegate addImageToModel:self];
    }
    else 
    {
         if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(badImage)])
            [self.delegate badImage];
    }

    tempImage = nil;
}
```

[image: Stack trace from Instruments]

Comment: Try by writing [tempImage release]; after  tempImage = nil;

Comment: @Marvin tempImage is already autoReleased, so it doesn't need to be released. In fact, if you release it there will be a crash.

Comment: Ta, but didn't stop the leak sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.image is getting set to tempImage, so it probably retains the image. Is it released anywhere?

Comment: Check for this both properties self.image, self.circleImage.

Comment: @daidai What object is self? Does self release image in its dealloc method? Is the dealloc method called?

Comment: Also, what does the addImageToModel: method do?

Comment: addImageToModel sends the ImageDownloader object / class to the Model

Comment: Note that the leak tool is only telling you when the leaked object was allocated. It doesn't tell you where the leak occurs. The leak be due to anything that causes a retain on the object. Also, is the tool indicating that the leaked object is a UIImage?

Comment: Yep, the Leaked Object is UIImage.

Comment: I think you need to include more code in the problem description for us to determine where the leak is occurring.

Comment: Another thing you should try is running the analyzer on your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write this line :

```
tempImage = nil;
```

Since tempImage is a function scope variable, it will be taking care of by itself.
Further more, if self.image is (nonatomic, assign) that could be the origine of your leak.

About the stack trace image, is this from leak instruments, or memory instruments ?

Unfortunately, until you give away some more code, we won't be able to help you further.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm confused about: "it will be taking care of by itself." - then why is there a leak?

Comment: Not sure it is coming from that... Can you post more info about self.image ?

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas mentioned, it may be self.image retaining the image?

Have you considered waking up the zombies ? ;)

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-05-20-the-inner-life-of-zombies.html

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Comment: It's not actually causing a crash, this is being picked up in Instruments, so the Zombies don't say anything.